# How to access the object inside a nested array from a JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the names from listitem array and have them printed/stored in a variable

This is the structure:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "pagemap": {    
    "listitem": [
     {
      "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight"
     },
     {
      "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight"
     },
     {
      "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight"
     },
     {
      "name": "Despicable Me 3"
     },
     {
      "name": "Slumber Party"
     },
     {
      "name": "Everything, Everything"
     },
     {
      "name": "Can We Still Be Friends?"
     },
     {
      "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight"
     },
     {
      "name": "Wonder Woman"
     },
     {
      "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight"
     }
    ]
   }
  }
```

I'm still new to node.js and this is how I extract it from the JSON

```
let{      
    items:[{
      pagemap: {
        listitem: [{              
        name                     
          }]
        }
    }]
} = showList;
```

**How would I get all the names inside listitem and have them stored on a variable so that I could print them?**

Answer (score 0):

```
let listItem = [];
showList.forEach((item) => {
    if(item && item.pagemap && item.pagemap.listitem){
       item.pagemap.listitem.forEach((lItem) => {
           if(lItem && lItem.name){
              listItem.push(lItem.name)
           }
       })
    }
})
```

Comment: Consider adding explaination for your code to help user understand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apparently, it doesn't show the log when I console.log the listItem array to know that it works, I guess it didn't, are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const results = {
 "items": [{
  "pagemap": {
   "listitem": [
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" },
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" },
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" },
    { "name": "Despicable Me 3" },
    { "name": "Slumber Party" },
    { "name": "Everything, Everything" },
    { "name": "Can We Still Be Friends?" },
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" },
    { "name": "Wonder Woman" },
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" }
   ]
  }
 }]
};

function nameOnly(listItem) {
    return listItem.name;
}
function resultItemsReducer(memo, item) {
    return memo.concat(item.pagemap.listitem.map(nameOnly));
}
const names = results.items.reduce(resultItemsReducer, []);
console.log(names);
```

`Array.reduce()` is well documented [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), as well as `Array.map()`.

Each function is pretty much self explanatory, but let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sadly it still doesn't log, what could be the problem here? pagemap is an object of **items**, there are like 10 pagemaps inside, but I only want the first pagemap which is the one posted above, I still can't find a way to access the names inside it

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for then. I edited the my response to include your object, so you can just click `Run this code`. Let me know if this is still not what you expect. If so, provide expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using jsonpath. The libs has a tool to query JSON based on the path. The guide of installation and usage is [here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath)

With regards to your question, by using jsonpath, you can access only "name" property such in your JSON object as below

```
var jsonpath = require('jsonpath');
var data = {
 "items": [{
  "pagemap": {
   "listitem": [
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" },
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" },
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" },
    { "name": "Despicable Me 3" },
    { "name": "Slumber Party" },
    { "name": "Everything, Everything" },
    { "name": "Can We Still Be Friends?" },
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" },
    { "name": "Wonder Woman" },
    { "name": "Transformers: The Last Knight" }
   ]
  }
 }]
};

// query only name from all listitem
var allnames = jsonpath.query(data, "$.items[0].pagemap.listitem[*].name")
console.log(allnames)

/* console.log on allnames returns - 
[ 'Transformers: The Last Knight',
  'Transformers: The Last Knight',
  'Transformers: The Last Knight',
  'Despicable Me 3',
  'Slumber Party',
  'Everything, Everything',
  'Can We Still Be Friends?',
  'Transformers: The Last Knight',
  'Wonder Woman',
  'Transformers: The Last Knight' ]
*/
```